# Refresh leaflet marker data in place ? (on insert to sql db)

Tags: leaflet, markers

I have a form that sends data via ajax to be geocoded and inserted into a mysql db.

Once that data is there, can I force the marker layer to refresh so that it displays the new data?

The SQL API for Cartodb includes a layer method .invalidate() which refreshes the data if there has been a change.  I don't care about detecting a change, but I do hope to find a similar refreshing capability in pure leaflet.

The map will not be resized or zoomed when the new data is pulled in, so something like map._onResize() won't have any effect.

There will be reference URLs etc that need to be pulled from the db to add to a popup, so just putting on the marker on the front end while pushing to the db via ajax won't work.